# Unix awk decimal export in pipe

Tags: awk, grep, pipe, floating-point

I'm struggling to adapt a script, which loops through a large number of individual files (subj_id), and prints out the value of $4 in a specified line.

Text file contains lines

```
# Measure Brain, ICV, Brain Volume, 1118718.609121, mm^3
```

My script contains this line to export the number 1118718:

```
printf "%g," `cat ${subj_id}/stats/aseg.stats | grep ICV | awk -F, '{print $4}'` > BrainVol.csv
```

My values are either `A) 666666.012345` or `B) 7777777.012345`, so the script runs fine with `A)` and exports `666666` but for case `B)` it exports `7777780`. I gather I need use printf to specify number of decimals for output 
but 
`'{printf "%.2f\n",$4}'` doesn't work.

Sorry this is too basic but what's the correct order in this pipe to include a decimal specifier (if that's the problem).

It's a bash script and I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about that `printf` doesn't work?

Comment: I used printf "%g," `cat ${subj_id}/stats/aseg.stats | grep Brain | awk -F, '{printf "%.2f\n",$4}` > BrainVol.csv which still gives output in scientific notation 1.21079e+06 if it's a 7777777.012345 number. Am I using it in the wrong place in the pipe, given that the entire line starts with printf?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
awk -F, '/ICV/ {printf "%.2f\n", $4}' ${subj_id}/stats/aseg.stats
```

where if I use the following source:

```
# Measure Brain, ICV, Brain Volume, 1118718.609121, mm^3
# Measure Brain, ICV, Brain Volume, 7777777.012345, mm^3
# Measure Brain, ICV, Brain Volume, 666666.012345, mm^3
```

I get the following output:

```
1118718.61
7777777.01
666666.01
```

As @glennjackman noted, we can make the match more specific by checking if the expected field is the exact string we want instead of matching a pattern anywhere in the line by doing

```
awk -F, '$2 == " ICV" {printf "%.2f\n", $4}' ${subj_id}/stats/aseg.stats
```

or if we want to be flexible about spaces we could match the pattern against only that field

```
awk -F, '$2 == /^[[:space:]]*ICV[[:space:]]*$/ {printf "%.2f\n", $4}' ${subj_id}/stats/aseg.stats
```

Comment: Thank you, Eric! That outputs 777777.01 correctly. One follow-up question. In the example I gave "ICV" is intentionally a unique string. But my inputs contain the word Brain so /BrainTotal/ is no longer unique. How do I modify the search to search for exact string, not any word that appears in string?

Comment: @julia I would do `awk -F, '$2 == " ICV" {...`